# angular ui-grid sorting failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using AngularJS UI-GRID. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, sorting is not working. When I click any of the field header, I get this error

```
Error: No sorting function found for type:undefined
at Object.d.guessSortFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:5:12652)
at Object.d.getSortFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:5:13861)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:5:14548
at Array.sort (native)
at Object.d.sort (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:5:14458)
at o.sortByColumn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:4:18984)
at c (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:4:14283)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js:4:14518
at l.promise.then.L (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:99:469)
at l.promise.then.L (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:99:469)
```

Here is my code:

```
$http.get('assets/json/gd.csv').success(function(data) {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        { name: 'Date', enableSorting: true },
        { name: 'Account Name', enableSorting: true },
        { name: 'Device Name', enableSorting: true },
        { name: 'Serial Number/UDI', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'Model', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'Device Type', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'Location', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'Inches Printed', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'Delta', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'RFID Valid', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'RFID Valid Delta', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'RFID Void', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'RFID Void Delta', enableSorting: true },
        { name : 'RFID Delta Total', enableSorting: true }
    ];

    $scope.myData = csvToArray(data);
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData;
});
```

When I first load the controller, the $scope.myData has a static array with 4 columns. The sorting works well at this point.

I have a generate report button that calls the above $http.get function. The retrieved csv has 14 fields which is converted into an array by csvtoArray. You will notice that the column increased from 4 to 14. The grid though is still being displayed properly without any issues. The only problem is with sorting. Clicking on any field will say "No sorting function ...." in console.

Comment: Try the **[latest build](http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js)** of ui-grid. Issue is **[mentioned here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1393)** and fix is [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/commit/1125cf1a62a16aa0be1dbbffd6525c682ce55c5b)

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I got it fixed by just making the fields on the array initialization the same. There are weird behaviors in ui-grid. I'm just thinking of writing my own simple table even without sorting, just displaying the data instead.